# JSON.parse with reviver function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am new to JSON and getting this exception while using reviver parameter in [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…).
```

Without reviver parameter code works fine but with reviver parameter it throws the above exception. Why is that happening ?

```js
var str = ' { ' +
    ' "name" : "Username", ' +
    ' "fname" : "Fathername" '
+ ' } ';

var jObj = JSON.parse(str, function (a, b) {
  console.log(a + "=>" + b);
});

document.write(
  "<h1>" + jObj.name + "</h1>",
  "<h2>" + jObj.fname + "</h2>"
);
```

Comment: Yes, it says 'undefined'.'

Comment: jObj returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Yes sure my bro :)

Comment: Bro can i connect with you on facebook. Need to talk with you. It will be glade. Please share your facebook time line URL here to connect with you via.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your reviver function returns implicitly `undefined`.

You have to return something, i.e. the variable `b`:

```js
var str = JSON.stringify({ name: 'Username', fname: 'Fathername' });

var jObj = JSON.parse(str, function (a, b) {
  console.log(a, '=>', b);
  return b;
});

document.write('<h1>' + jObj.name + '</h1>', '<h2>' + jObj.fname + '</h2>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return the value in `JSON.parse`.
here is an example, with more pretty code:

```js
var str = '{"name": "Username", "fname": "Fathername"}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(str, (key, value) => {
             return value;
         });
 document.write(
     "<h1>" + parsed.name + "</h1>",
     "<h2>" + parsed.fname + "</h2>"
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `reviver` [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter):

> If the reviver function returns undefined (or returns no value, e.g. if execution falls off the end of the function), the property is deleted from the object.

which is exactly what happens here. Because there is no `return` statement in your reviver function, it implicitly returns undefined. Below you can see an equivalent:

```
function (a,b) {
  console.log(a + "=>" + b);
  return undefined;
}
```

So in this scenario, `JSON.parse` actually parses your string to an object correctly, but then puts its properties through the reviver function, which returns undefined for all of them. This results in `undefined` being returned.

If you want to make it parse your object correctly, you might either return value explicitly:

```
var jObj = JSON.parse(str,function(a,b){
  console.log(a + "=>" + b);
  return b;
});
```

or remove reviver all together:

```
var jObj = JSON.parse(str);
```