# What is the problem with this JSON.parse reviver function?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following:

```js
const whitelist = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'result'];
const reviver = (key, value) => {
  if (whitelist.includes(key)) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return undefined; // explicitly delete the entry
  }
};

const theMightyJsonString = '{ "result": { "prop1": "Greetings", "prop2": "Hello", "prop3": "WASSUP!!!!" } }';

console.log(JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString))
console.log(JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString, reviver))
```

Now, I can successfully `JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString)` into an object, but if I pass in my reviver like so `JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString, reviver)` the result is `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The top level object has an empty key (`undefined` maybe?). `whitelist.includes(undefined)` will be `false`.

Comment: you are passing the entire json obj into the receiver, so you will only receive one item with the key 'results' and the value being the rest of your data, which will not match any of your whitelist values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.parse with reviver function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211345/json-parse-with-reviver-function-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last call to reviver will happen with an empty string as the key `""`, which allows you to apply a transformation to the final object (in your case, you're transforming it to `undefined`). If you add a test for the empty string then it works properly:

```js
const whitelist = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'result'];
const reviver = (key, value) => {
  if (whitelist.includes(key) || key === '') {
    return value;
  } else {
    return undefined; // explicitly delete the entry
  }
};

const theMightyJsonString = '{ "result": { "prop1": "Greetings", "prop2": "Hello", "prop3": "WASSUP!!!!" } }';

console.log( JSON.parse( theMightyJsonString, reviver ) );
```

Comment: I see. I thought the final object was being skipped. I actually only added the surrounding curly braces to make a valid JSON string after parse() threw a SyntaxError without them. (https://www.json.org/) Thanks for your answer and good use of code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) explains:

> If a `reviver` is specified, the value computed by parsing is transformed before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties (beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself) are individually run through the `reviver`.

The "and proceeding to the original value itself" answers your question.
 `JSON.parse()` calls the `reviver` with the keys `'prop1'`, `'prop2'`, `'prop3'` and their associated values, then with the key `'result'` and its value (an object) and one last time with an empty string as `key` and the entire parsed object as `value`.

The documentation also provides the solution to your problem:

> If the `reviver` only transforms some values and not others, be certain to return all untransformed values as-is, otherwise they will be deleted from the resulting object.

Your code should look like:

```js
const whitelist = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'result'];
const reviver = (key, value) => {

  if (key === '' || whitelist.includes(key)) {
    return value;
  } else {
    return undefined; // explicitly delete the entry
  }
};

const theMightyJsonString = '{ "result": { "prop1": "Greetings", "prop2": "Hello", "prop3": "WASSUP!!!!" } }';

console.log(JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString))
console.log(JSON.parse(theMightyJsonString, reviver))
```